# Use FFMPEG to get frame from a video on specific time (PHP)

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG, I want to get the frame from the video on a specific time (provided by the user) in PHP.
Can anybody help me with this? I've never used FFMPEG.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

```
//video dir
$video = 'Salient.avi';
//where to save the image
$image = 'testimage%d.jpg';
//time to take screenshot at
$interval = '00:00:12';
//screenshot size
$size = '535x346';
echo "Starting ffmpeg...\n\n<br>";
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $video -ss $interval -f image2 -s $size -vframes 1 $image"; 
echo shell_exec($cmd);
echo "Done.\n";
```